# "Between" Two Locations

Tags: grammar, prepositions, formality, among-between

I am typing up formal invitations, and I want to say that transportation will be provided from Point A to Point B (but also from Point B back to Point A).

In order to clear up the to-from/from-to confusion, I tried to use 'between' as follows:

> Transportation will be provided between Point A and Point B.

Is it grammatically correct to use between in this manner?

Transportation is really **FROM** Point A **TO** Point B -- although the car may travel *between* the two locations (i.e. not at either end point but in the middle), the transportation itself is to/from specific locations.

Another option is to say

> Transportation will be provided *to and from* Point A **and** Point B.

I am trying to find the most appropriate choice of preposition to accurately convey the meaning, and I was unsuccessful in determining this after searching myself.

Comment: Do you think some Ferris Bueller-type might want to take a spin around town for awhile *between* A and B in your carriage?

Answer (score 1):

First, “grammatically correct” is not something that applies here. **Of course** it is grammatically correct. That doesn’t mean it’s sensible — nor that it isn’t.  This is not a matter of grammar, but of semantics.

So now for semantics, which is all that ever matters. You misunderstand the semantics of *between*. Your error is thinking that *between A and B* only applies in the direction A → B, the way *from A to B* would.  It does not. That simply is not how *between* is normally used.  *Between* implies a reciprocal or bidirectional connection, so A ↔ B in this case.

This is easily seen in statements regarding shuttle services between two or more locations.  For example:

> - Complimentary shuttle service will be provided **between the Convention Center and official APHA Annual Meeting hotels** except for those within walking distance. APHA will offer an extra shuttle route between the Convention Center and the Hilton New Orleans Riverside for easy access between scientific sessions. <sup>(http://www.apha.org/meetings/registration/Shuttle.htm)</sup>
> - Continuous shuttle service is provided every 10 – 15 minutes **between TechEd 2014 conference hotels and the George R. Brown Convention Center** (GRBCC) on the following schedule.  <sup>(http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/TechEd/TechEdShuttles#fbid=)</sup>
> - Free shuttle service is provided **between all terminals and remote parking lots**. <sup>(http://www.supershuttle.com/Locations/LAXAirportShuttleLosangeles.aspx)</sup>

So don’t fret.  Just use *between* like everybody else does.

Comment: While I agree with what you say about *between* I think for the OP's purposes it's worth drawing explicit attention to the fact that all your examples use *shuttle service* and that that phrase also and in itself conveys the "both directions" idea. So I would suggest that "A shuttle service will be provided between points A and B" instead of "Transportation.." would help make things clear in their invitation.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the asker’s concerns. He is not worried that _between_ implies only one direction, but rather that it may imply that the transportation never reaches Point A or Point B, going instead around in circles within the area between the two points. A possible interpretation, of course, but a most unlikely one.

Answer (score 0):

"From A to B and back" works if one's intention is to state that it's not a one-way trip.

Comment: I agree with this.  Simple, precise, and space-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Transportation will be provided both ways between Point A and Point B.

or

> Transportation will be provided between Point A and Point B in both directions.

Comment: *Between* already has the both-ways aspect built right into it.

Comment: @tchrist - The problem is that it's ambiguous: it *can* mean 'both ways', but it doesn't mean that exclusively. The OP's concern is to eliminate what they describe as "the to-from/from-to confusion" in the invitation, so it's best to spell out explicitly what is on offer. It would be different if the OP was describing an established travel service such as those you referred to in your posting, but since a special invitation implies a one-off event, its recipients would not be able to make the same assumptions as would be valid, say, for a shuttle service between a hotel and a conference centre